# Merge two vectors without sorting them in C++

Tags: c++, merge

I have two vectors that I want to merge without sorting the elements:

```
A = [a d f h]
B = [b c e g]
C = [a d f h b c e g]  // I want this
```

`std::merge` and `std::inplace_merge` end up sorting the vectors. Is there any way of doing this other than manually reading the two vectors in succession and pushing the values into a new vector?

Comment: You want to "append" or "concatenate", not "merge".

Comment: Another example of the importance of learning accurate and precise terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
vector<T> C(A);
C.insert(C.end(), B.begin(), B.end());
```